# keras errors with theano/tensowflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras

I found some strange problems when I use keras.
My system is ubuntu 14.04/64bit

theano backend error info:

```
Using Theano backend.
Using gpu device 0: Tesla K20Xm (CNMeM is enabled with initial size: 80.0% of memory, cuDNN not available)
Train on 1000 samples, validate on 100 samples
Epoch 1/5
Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

tensorflow backed error info:

```
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:316] current context was not created by the StreamExecutor cuda_driver API: 0x2420480; a CUDA runtime call was likely performed without using a StreamExecutor context
```

It's OK when I use theano run CNN and tensowflow run LSTM.
But when I use theano run LSTM or use tensorflow run CNN, the error was occupied.

And it's usually some program load 80% gpu memory and never actually run. Or sometime the result is far different for the CPU result.(CPU result is right)

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs with Tensorflow when you have another program accessing the GPU at the same time. In your case it is clear that Theano is being loaded prior to Tensorflow. So either somewhere in your code on in Keras Theano is accidentally being loaded. One sure fire way of avoiding this issue is to uninstall Theano (from your current conda env/virtualenv).